# How to different action perform on click tableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to action perfrom on tableViewCell

problem is that - if i click on cell(when size (375 * 667) it must perform one action, And if i click on cell (when size (375 * 300) must perform other action

Comment: Rather than checking the *view* declare and maintain an appropriate indicator in the *model*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the dimensions...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.frame.height == 667) {
        //do something
    } else if (tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.frame.height == 300) {
        //do something else
    }

}
```